# Why is it unlucky to walk under a ladder?

Tags: superstition

If we ignore the practical safety issues, why is it considered unlucky to walk under a ladder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Richard Webster addresses this well-known superstition in *The Encyclopedia of Superstitions* and gives three theories for its origin:

> Walking under a ladder is believed to cause bad luck. No one really knows why, but at least three theories have been proposed. The most likely theory is that a ladder forms a triangle when placed against a wall. The triangle symbolizes the Holy Trinity. Consequently, when you walk through it, you effectively insult the Trinity and attract the devil. The second theory concerns the use of a ladder in hangings. The ladder would be propped against a beam to allow the person about to be hanged to climb high enough to reach the rope. A third theory dates back to ancient Egyptian times, when people believed you might see a god walking up or down the ladder while you walked under it.
>
> <sub>Webster, R. (2008). The encyclopedia of superstitions. Woodbury, Minn.: Llewellyn Publications.</sub>

A version of the hangings theory can also be found in the much older *Encyclopaedia of Superstitions, Folklore and the Occult Sciences of the World*:

> The reason why it is believed to be unlucky to pass under a ladder, is because, in old times, convicts who were condemned to death were made to pass under a ladder; while those who were not condemned to death passed outside.
>
> <sub>Daniels, C. (1903). Encyclopaedia of superstitions, folklore, and the occult sciences of the world.</sub>

Comment: Thank you, this is a very interesting answer.

Comment: You are welcome @Bloom. There's no need to rush to mark it as accepted thought. You might want to wait a while to see if other answers appear.